# Generating PDF in php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am using the following code to generate pdf in php but when I open file it shows `corrupted or damaged file` error.

```
$FileName = date("d-m-y") . '.pdf';
$Content = "";

# Titlte of the CSV
$Content = "Name,Address,Age,Phone \n";

# fill data in the CSV
$Content .= "\"John Doe\",\"New York, USA\",15,65465464 \n";

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"');
echo $Content;
exit();
```

Comment: What do you use for generating PDF file? Any library? As far as I see if this is all the code - you have to render the PDF file with the use of library like **UTCPDF** (good UTF support).

Comment: Use mpdf, its best, I have used it. http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/download

Comment: tcpdf is better than those said before this comment. fact.

Comment: try to write the file hosting server and see in pdf is created properly.usually when i face this problem, its either the header function or output buffer thant causes the problem

Comment: Do you _seriously_ think that if you just _label_ any kind of text data (CSV format here) as “this is a PDF”, it will magically become one …?

Answer (score 3):

PDF is a binary file, you can't do it this way. I'd suggest to use some PDF framework, like [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/). PHP itself has also [libraries for PDF](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php), but it's still much better (and less effort) to use a framework.

Comment: Please avoid fpdf. Its best days are long over. I've been using it for five years now, and wishing I could switch.

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://www.tcpdf.org/ in the past, works very well and is very complete and FLOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using MPDF library 
http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/download

this library is robust and can convert html to pdf directly